# Sending Email while accessing fields from SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, singleemailmessage, massemailmessage

`Parent_Project_if_applicable__r` is a lookup relationship on the Case object to the `Parent_Project_if_applicable__c` object.  The If Block will send a group of emails to the addresses pulled from the Private Method `getAddresses()` so I have a mass email in that Block.  The Else block will send a single message to an email address pulled from the `cl.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c`.

Receiving the error message:
`Line: 25, Column: 30
Variable does not exist: toAddresses`

Also wondering if my syntax within the If and Else block is correct to access the fields from SOQL.

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                             FROM Case
                                             WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
                                             GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                             HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 8];



Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();
                    for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){

                        Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
                        AcctIds.add(accId);
                }

                List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c, 
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c,
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];

            for(Case cl:caseList){
                if(cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project'){    
                    Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();     
                    mail.toAddresses = getAddresses(); 
                    mail.Subject = 'Subject Test Message';
                    mail.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + cl.Account.Name + ' has ' + (Integer)cl.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
                        }
                else{  
                   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    message.toAddresses = cl.Parent_Project_If_Applicable__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c;
                    message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + cl.Account.Name + ' has ' + cl.co + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
                    }
                }
private List<String> getAddresses(){
List<User> UserList =
        [SELECT id, name, email
        FROM User 
        WHERE id 
        IN (SELECT userorgroupid 
            FROM groupmember
            WHERE group.name = 'Customer Success Managers')];

List<String> emailString = new List<String>();

for(User u: UserList){
    emailstring.add(u.email);
}   
return (emailString);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to point out the specific line that is throwing the error.  There are no line numbers in the display so it is hard for us to find it easily.

Comment: The error is in the line `mail.toAddresses = getAddresses();`

Answer (score 0):

The [`Messaging.MassEmailMessage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) does not have a `toAddresses` property. With that class, you specify target objects via `setTargetObjectIds()`, which accepts a list of Id values of Contacts, Users, or Leads.

It appears that you probably meant to declare the variable `mail` as `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.

As a first step in debugging, it's important to validate *types*. This is something that's underlain a number of your questions so far. The error message won't necessarily tell you exactly what is wrong, because the compiler does not understand your intent. However, it can tell you *where* something has gone wrong.

Here, it's that the identifier `mail.toAddresses` is not meaningful to the compiler. With that knowledge in hand, you can back-trace through your code to identify *what kind of value* you are working with. Seeing that it's a `Messaging.MassEmailMessage` instance, you can open the Apex Developer Guide (which I've linked above) to learn what is and is not available with that type of value.

Apex is a strongly-typed language. You cannot mix and match values across types, and many of the compile-time errors you'll encounter result from mismatches in types. It's critical to get comfortable chasing down that type, pun intended, of issue.